# Use of the "Aloha SSO" button that sometimes appears on Login Screen

Tags: single-sign-on, new

I see this button when I call the login page from a Google Chrome Incognito modus and can't make any sense out of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aloha is an internal Salesforce environment, this is probably a bug. Open a case with Salesforce and let them know.